# How to debug adblock browser on android

Tags: android, jquery, debugging, adblock

I've got a project that's currently running fine on virtually every web browser/device except on mobile using the web browser called 'Adblock Browser' located here: 
https://adblockbrowser.org/

I have tried using chrome's remote emulation but it doesn't recognize this browser. So I have no idea how to debug why my page isn't loading in this browser and fail to see any documentation regarding how to debug it.

This web browser was made by the people who created Adblock Plus, which will display my page fine running in other browsers, but their own browser won't display my page. There is nothing in the blockable list of ABP on my page that should be triggering anything, and I have no ads on my page.

How can I debug this browser? 
and/or why would this browser not be displaying my page when the plugin will? 
And just to add some more detail to that problem - I have a jQuery call on document ready that hides a loading div and displays another div - and adblock browser will not trigger these events, it will only show my loading div but does not transition.

Also - it doesn't make a difference whether I disable ad blocking on the page or request the desktop site, it still won't load it.

Comment: Well, sounds like this browser doesnt like the javascript.
Instead of hiding one div and showing another, you could just load the content into the same div? Or try similar changes to work around problem.

Comment: yeah - I am going to give this a shot - I am just slightly annoyed that they would release a web browser that has 10+ million installations and offer no way for developers to interact with it from a debugging standpoint.

Answer (score 0):

I guess answering my own question - adblock browser will not display an alert in an included file if the entire file is not valid - so stepping through and separating code into different files and seeing when the alert stops is how I was able to debug my problem.

And the problem was that adblock browser does not support the javascript syntax 'let' - and completely broke my page because of it. So in conclusion, I hate adblock browser.